# Linear equations problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a system $AX=0$ where
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If $ad-bc=0$ and some entry of $A$ is different from $0$ then there is a solution $(p,q)$ such that $(x,y)$ is solution iff there is a scaler $t$ such that $x=tp, y=tq$
What i have been able to achieve so for is that if $ad-bc\neq0$ then the system has a trivial solution only and if every entry of $A$ is zero then every pair $(x, y)$ is solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $(p,q)$ is a solution to the system, we have that:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} p\\ q \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
ap + b q = 0\\
cp + dq = 0\\
\end{array}
\right. 
\left\{\begin{array}{l} t\cdot (ap + bq) =t\cdot 0\\ t\cdot(cp+dq) = t\cdot 0 \end{array} \right.
$

Can you prove that $(tp,tq)$ is a solution to the initial equation (try to reform the above equations in a matrix form)?

Answer (score 2):

The set of points $x$ such that $Ax=0$ forms a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

This subspace cannot have dimension $0$ because $Ax=0$ does not have a single solution.

The subspace cannot have dimension $2$ because if it did it would be all of $\mathbb R^2$ and that only happens if $A$ is the zero matrix.

Therefore, the solution space is one-dimensional and so it has a basis vector, call it $(p,q)$. Then for any $t\in\mathbb R$ $t(p,q)=(tp,tq)$ is a solution.